# Use the Mean Value Theorem to show that the following is true: $e^{x}\ge\frac{x\cos x+1}{\cos x+x\sin x}$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

> Use the Mean Value Theorem to show that the following is true: $$e^{x}\ge\frac{x\cos x+1}{\cos x+x\sin x}.$$

This is the given function I'm working with: $f\left(x\right)=e^{x}\cdot\cos x$.

From my understanding we should have the boundaries $[a,b]$ where $c$ is located and I have no idea on how to do that. How do I proceed? Any hints?

So this is how it is solved on my textbook but i don't get it:

The conditions of MVT are true for [0, x] segment. Since
$f'\left(x\right)=e^{x}\left(\cos x-\sin x\right)$ and $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$:

$$e^{c}\left(\cos c-\sin c\right)=\frac{f\left(x\right)-f\left(0\right)}{\left(x-0\right)}=\frac{e^{x}\cos x-1}{x}, 0<c<x$$

But $$0<c<x$$
$$0<\sin c<\sin x$$

and
$$\cos x<\cos c<1$$

and $$1<e^c < e^x$$

By using these inequalities, we get:

$$e^{x}\left(\cos x\right)-1=xe^{c}\left(\cos c-\sin c\right)=xe^{c}\cos c-xe^{c}\sin c\ge x\cdot1\cdot\cos c-xe^{x}\sin x$$

So, $$e^{x}\cos x-1\ge x\cdot1\cdot\cos c-xe^{x}\sin x$$
$$e^{x}\cos x+xe^{x}\sin x\ge x\cos c+1$$
$$e^{x}\cos x+xe^{x}\sin x\ge x\cos x+1$$
$$e^{x}\ge\frac{x\cos x+1}{\cos x+x\sin x}$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119466/discussion-on-question-by-greasyllama-use-the-mean-value-theorem-to-show-that-th).